# Having trouble with error taking address of temporary fpermissive

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to open a file and read a block of text, for example: Manufacturer 0, Technology 1.11

I keep getting that error though and I'm not quite sure how to correct the issue. Is it because I'm calling a double a string?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>    
#include "Company.h"
#include "Technology.h"
#include "Manufacturer.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //Creates an array of pointers to the Company class (size 20).
    Company * portfolio[20];
    string company, cost;
    //Open the input file for reading.
   ifstream in("company.txt");
   if (!in) {
       cout << "File not found!!\n";
       exit(0);
   }
    
    cout << "Original Portfolio" << endl;
     //Reads and add into array
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 && in >> company >> cost; i++){
       cost = cost.substr(1);
       if (company == "Manufacturer") {
           portfolio[i] = &Manufacturer(stod(cost));
       }
       else {
           portfolio[i] = &Technology(stod(cost));
       }
       cout << portfolio[i]->toString() << endl;
   }
   in.close();

   //Writes into file
   ofstream out("company.txt");
   cout << "\n\nUpdated Portfolio" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       portfolio[i]->update();
       cout << portfolio[i]->toString() << endl;
       out << portfolio[i]->toString() << endl;
   }
   out.close();
};
```

My error initially occurs here

`portfolio[i] = &Manufacturer(stod(cost));`

Here's the full project in hasebin: https://hasteb.in/yuqeyiji.cpp

for readability sake, I put all 4 files in one link.

Comment: `&` -> `new `? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If e.g. `Manufacturer` is a class, then `Manufacturer(stod(cost))` will create a *temporary* object, a so-called *rvalue* (please read more about [the different value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)). This temporary object will be destructed once the assignment is finished, making the stored pointer invalid. Therefore you can't store pointers to rvalues.

Assuming that `Manufacturer` and `Technology` are polymorphic classes inheriting from the common `Company` base class, then you should create these objects dynamically using `new`. Or better yet, use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for their creation.

Something like this (which also uses a vector instead of an array):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Company>> portfolio;
...
portfolio.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Manufacturer>(stod(cost)));
...
```